# Sinatra with Postgres and ActiveRecord | Error Pushing to Heroku is: Invalid DATABASE_URL

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku, sinatra

I have an application written in Sinatra that works locally but that I cannot seem to push up to heroku.

When I attempt to push to heroku I get the following error:

> -----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
>         Could not detect rake tasks
>         ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app with no environment variables present
>         and using the production group of your Gemfile.
>         This may be intentional, if you expected rake tasks to be run
>         cancel the build (CTRL+C) and fix the error then commit the fix:
>         rake aborted!
>         Invalid DATABASE_URL

My Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'sinatra', require: 'sinatra/base'
gem "pg"
gem "activerecord"
gem "sinatra-activerecord"
gem "rake"

gem 'minitest', require: false
gem 'rack-test', require: false
gem 'faraday'
gem 'json'
gem 'minitest-reporters'
```

My database.yml file

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: calendar_development
  host: localhost
  password:

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: calendar_test
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  password:
```

My config.ru

```
require './app'
run Sinatra::Application

ENV['RACK_ENV'] ||= 'development'
```

Procfile

```
web: bundle exec rackup config.ru -p $PORT
```

Rakefile

```
require "sinatra/activerecord/rake"
require 'rake/testtask'
require "./app"

task :default => :test
env = ENV["SINATRA_ENV"] || "development"

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.libs << 'test'
  t.test_files = FileList["test/**/*_test.rb"]
  t.verbose = false
end
```

The app.rb

```
require 'sinatra' 
require 'sinatra/activerecord'
require 'json'
Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/models/*.rb'].each {|file| require file }

env_index = ARGV.index("-e")
env_arg = ARGV[env_index + 1] if env_index
env = env_arg || ENV["SINATRA_ENV"] || "development"

use ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement # close connection to the DDBB properly...https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/59
databases = YAML.load_file("config/database.yml")
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(databases[env])

if env == 'test'
  User.destroy_all
end
```

Comment: Can you try to edit your config.ru file to remove the last line, so that you have this: ```require './app'
run Sinatra::Application```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I removed all the environment test from my app.rb file and moved it to environments:

app.rb

> ```
> require './config/environments'
> ```

Then I changed the DB setup - first of all, removed all the ENV[SINATRA_ENV]

environments.rb

> ```
> configure :production, :development, :test do
>   db = URI.parse(ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || 'postgres://localhost/calendar_development')
>
>   ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
>       :adapter => db.scheme == 'postgres' ? 'postgresql' : db.scheme,
>       :host     => db.host,
>       :username => db.user,
>       :password => db.password,
>       :database => db.path[1..-1],
>       :encoding => 'utf8'
>   )
> end
> ```

I changed my Rakefile

> ```
> namespace :db do
>   task :seed do
>     seed_file = File.join('db/seeds.rb')
>     load(seed_file) if File.exist?(seed_file)
>   end
> end
> ```

I followed sybohy's advice and in my config.ru file, I removed the last line - leaving

config.ru

> ```
> require './app'
> run Sinatra::Application
> ```

I ran:

> heroku addons | grep POSTGRES

grabbed the name of the db (HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_JADE)

> heroku pg:reset HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_JADE

and then migrated

> heroku run rake db:migrate

---

So far this seems to have fixed the errors! I will update if I find more!